# Papaparse Angular service

Tags: angularjs, papaparse

Coding is new to me and I tried to play with Papaparse and AngularJS. My code is below. I seem to miss something and hope someone could help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <p>{{test}}</p>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.service('papa', function() {
      Papa.parse("test.csv", {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: function(results) {
          console.log(results.data);
        }
      })
    });

    app.controller('mainController', function($scope, papa) {
      $scope.test = papa;
      console.log($scope.test);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of letting us guess, tell us what you expect this code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: The service doesn't return anything. Suggest using a `$q` promise and resolve that promise in the parse complete callback. Return that promise from a function bound to the service

Comment: If you want to use PapaParse with Angular consider looking into https://github.com/Alberthaff/ngx-papaparse there are great examples there also.